Deforming instances along a curve geometry nodes
I'm hoping someone can help as I can't work it out and can't find the answer anywhere.
What I have is an object instanced along a spline, and I want to deform these instances based on a curve, which seems possible following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NaQq5CGUbs&ab_channel=OpenClass.
However, whilst it seems to work fine with a normal object, it doesn't seem to like my instances even after realizing them into one mesh. The effect seems to work on only one instance and leave the rest.
I've added the note setup for this part, so if anyone can let me know where I'm going wrong please do!

I should add that if I scale the instances before deforming along the curve, the result is closer but causes strange stretching at the ends.

